# how to set multiple Font Styles when checked Combobox in c#

Tags: c#

I'd like to font style and font size in Combobox. When I selected font size after selected font style then, I select font style in Combobox again it did not work.

How can I solve it?

```
private void FontBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(FontBox.Text, RichTextBox.Font.Size);
    }
    catch { }
}

private void font_sizeBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        RichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(RichTextBox.Font.FontFamily, 
            float.Parse(font_sizeBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean something like this? https://www.cyotek.com/files/articleimages/font-combobox.png

Comment: want to work together 'Font style combobox' and 'Font size combobox' together

Comment: Is the thing that you're trying to achieve similar to the image?

Comment: actually yes...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789825/10216583) could help if you speak VB.NET.

Answer (score 2):

To display the fonts in a `ComboBox` with it's respective styles, we have to set the ComboBox `DrawMode` property from, `Normal` to `DrawItemFixed`. Then we can use the DrawItem event:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.DrawItem += comboBox1_DrawItem;
        comboBox1.DataSource = System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families.ToList();
    }
```

Here, we're creating the Method `comboBox1_DrawItem` and assigning the DataSource for the ComboBox as the current installed Font-families.

```
    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        var fontFamily = (FontFamily)comboBox.Items[e.Index];
        var font = new Font(fontFamily, comboBox.Font.SizeInPoints);

        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(font.Name, font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    }
```

Then this should be the `DrawItem` method. You can also set `comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;` in the public of your form.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting like this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = newFont;
```

Comment: sorry,, i mean retain Fontstyle, size

Comment: when i select other FontStyle or Fontsize in combobox

Comment: first select all text and then apply font setting..give it a try